# How to compare if a field starts with a letter or number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to compare if a field starts with a letter or numeric.

```
Example.

Location.
234848383
664646663
322327772
678862622
HONDURAS
272828833
BRAZIL
PANAMA
UNITED KINGDOM
232332222
```

This my current query

```
SELECT
    dateho.UnitSysId,
    tempvehi.LicencePlate as Economico,
    case when SUBSTRING(prm_dcs.Tipo,1,1) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) then 'Heavy' else 'Not heavy' end as Tipo,
            ROUND((dateho.MaxHorasUsoAcumulada - (dateho.MinHorasUsoAcumulada - dateho.MinHorasUso)), 2) as HorasDeUsoMotorPrd
    into #final_table
FROM
    #DatosOdoHoro dateho INNER JOIN #tmpVehiclesAllAccount tempvehi ON dateho.UnitSysId = tempvehi.UnitSysId
                         INNER JOIN PRM.dbo.[prm_DetalleCamiones_Sabana_Estandar] prm_dcs on dateho.UnitSysId = prm_dcs.UnitSysId --AND prm_dcs.UnitSysId= 272729870
ORDER BY
    UnitSysId
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to determine if a string starts with a digit, then

`case when SUBSTRING(prm_dcs.Tipo,1,1) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) then 'Heavy' else 'Not heavy' end as Tipo`

can be written as:

`case when prm_dcs.Tipo like '[0-9]%' then 'Heavy' else 'Not heavy' end as Tipo`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    dateho.UnitSysId,
    tempvehi.LicencePlate as Economico,
    case when (prm_dcs.Tipo like '[0-9]%') then 'Heavy' else 'Not heavy' end as Tipo,
            ROUND((dateho.MaxHorasUsoAcumulada - (dateho.MinHorasUsoAcumulada - dateho.MinHorasUso)), 2) as HorasDeUsoMotorPrd
    into #final_table
FROM
    #DatosOdoHoro dateho INNER JOIN #tmpVehiclesAllAccount tempvehi ON dateho.UnitSysId = tempvehi.UnitSysId
                         INNER JOIN PRM.dbo.[prm_DetalleCamiones_Sabana_Estandar] prm_dcs on dateho.UnitSysId = prm_dcs.UnitSysId --AND prm_dcs.UnitSysId= 272729870
ORDER BY
    UnitSysId
```

Comment: It's correct, but some data are like 219066 06AM3A, some recommendation